# is .bashrc getting run twice when entering a new bash instance?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to display the number of nested sub-shells in my bash prompt.

I often type ":sh" during a vim editing session in order to do something, then exit back to the editor.  Sometimes I attempt to exit back to the editor out of habit, forgetting that I am not in any editing session and my terminal closes!

To avoid this, I added a bit of code to my .bashrc that would keep a count of the number of nested sub-shells and display it in the prompt.

Here is the code:

```
echo "1: SHLVL=$SHLVL"

if [[ -z $SHPID ]] ; then

 echo "2: SHLVL=$SHLVL"

 SHPID=$$

 let "SHLVL = ${SHLVL:0} + 1"
fi

echo "3: SHLVL=$SHLVL"
```

(For those who may wonder, the test "-z $SHPID" insures that $SHLVL won't get incremented again if I run ". .bashrc" again in the same shell, perhaps to test something.)

But the output looks like this:

```
lsiden@morpheus ~ (morpheus) (2) $ bash
1: SHLVL=3
2: SHLVL=3
3: SHLVL=4
lsiden@morpheus ~ (morpheus) (4) $ ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD
10421 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
11363 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
11388 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

As you can see, there are now two instances of bash on the stack, but the variable $SHLVL has been incremented twice.  The output shows that before this snippet of code even executes in my .bashrc, SHLVL has already been incremented by 1!

Is it possible for .bashrc to get run twice somehow without seeing the output of the echo commands?

Answer (score 2):

`SHLVL` is incremented automatically whenever you fire up a shell:

```
~$ echo $SHLVL
1
~$ bash -c 'echo $SHLVL'
2
```

and then you're incrementing it again in the `.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes you did, and the shell is already doing what you're trying to do :)